# How to clear swap files in Mac

Tags: xcode, macos, memory-leaks, swapfile

I'm making a small project using Xcode 4.2 which uses the current versions of the following libraries - Ogre3d, ArUco, Bullet (using OgreBullet wrapper) and OpenCv. I'm facing a big problem with the swap files presumably due to memory leak in Xcode.
RAM usage of Xcode increases after every few builds & run.

*And the major issue:* my swap files keep growing at an alarming pace to near about 10Gb after 3-4 hours of work forcing me to reboot the machine to clear it off as I run out of disk space.

Is there a way to release this swap space without reboot? Thnx!

*There have been a lot of similar problems reported in a number of mac forums but no clear solution is mentioned anywhere.

Comment: Can we migrate this question to super user? it has a lot of views and upvotes. This might actually get an answer.

Comment: @Whitecat sure.

Comment: I wrote a comment to moderators to do the migration.

Comment: @Whitecat thanks for the help. I wasn't aware of the process.